# Removing gray gradiant from UITabBar

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

This is the first time I'm using a UITabBar and I'm having problems getting it looking the way I want to look.

Right now it still has some grey shadow over cast over it. I cannot seem to remove this!

I've added this line to my code but the shadow still keeps showing up:

```
    self.universalTabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow");
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the rendering mode of each tab bar item's image.

```
universalTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
for tabBarItem in universalTabBar.items! {
    tabBarItem.image = image.imageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor()).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
}
```